# how to pass two arrays from model file to controller file

Tags: codeigniter

I want to return two arrays in a single function in the model and post the result in view but it gives an error.
And also I want to output a certain element of an array.

```
  public function index(){   
     $this->load->model("model");              

     $array['thisarray'] =  $this->model->Hello();

     $arrayy['yep'] = $this->model->Hello();

     $this->load->view("viewfile",$array);

     $this->load->view("viewfile",$arrayy);
          }
```

below is my model.php file.

```
   public function Hello()
            {
            return ['title' => 'My Title','heading' => 'My Heading']; 

             return ['a'=> "helo",'b' =>"yello", 'c' =>"mello"];
            }
```

below is my view file

```
 <?php
echo "<pre>";  
print_r($thisarray); 
print_r($yep)   
echo "</pre>"
?>
```

it gives an error saying yep is undefined variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is impossible

a possible solution would be

**your model**

```
public function Hello()
{
    return 
        [
            'yep' => ['title' => 'My Title','heading' => 'My Heading'],
            'thisarray' => ['a'=> "helo",'b' =>"yello", 'c' =>"mello"]
        ];
}
```

**your controller**

```
public function index()
{   
    $this->load->model("model");              
    $this->load->view("viewfile",$this->model->Hello());
}
```

and your view stays the same

Answer (score 0):

you need to just change just your controller like this and you are all set.

```
public function index()
{   
     $this->load->model("model");              

     $array['thisarray'] =  $this->model->Hello();

     $array['yep'] = $this->model->Hello();

     $this->load->view("viewfile", $array);
}
```

After modifying your controller like given above, you will be able to access you array as you are accessing it in your view.